# Unix, find, ls, grep and sort

Tags: unix

With this Unix command, I try to search text in a directory

```
find . -type f -iname *index*jsp -print | xargs ls -t | xargs grep body
```

`./apache-tomcat-6.0.18/a/index.jsp:<body>`
`./apache-tomcat-6.0.18/b/index.jsp: <body>`

But this result is not perfect, I want to get the file creation date and line number of matched string, like

`./apache-tomcat-6.0.18/a/index.jsp: 2011-1-2 Line 3`
`./apache-tomcat-6.0.18/b/index.jsp: 2011-1-1 Line 4`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should ask this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: No, dammit.  SO is for programming questions, and shell programming is PROGRAMMING!

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: No it isn't, unless you actually write an entire program. This is trivial one-liner.

Comment: @leppie - it is not a one-liner, and it is in the Shell Programming Language - which indicates that it is a question about Shell Programming, which is Programming, which is on-topic for SO.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: You should tell Atwood that unix.stackexchange.com is redundant in that case.

Comment: @leppie: I would if I thought it would make any difference; askubuntu too.  The questions there are basically marginally specialized duplicates of what would be appropriate for SO or SF or SU.  If you're going to push every Unix question out to one of the cinderella sites, what is left for SO but to rename itself ['BSOD'](http://acronymfinder/BSOD.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you might want to do to get the format you want is something like (in bash/Linux, not tested):

```
find . -type f -iname \*index\*jsp -print |
while read f; do
  if grep -q body "$f"; then
    modified_time=`stat -f %c "$f"`
    match_line=`awk '/body/ {print NR; exit}' "$f"`
    echo "$f $modified_time Line $match_line"
  fi
done
```

Comment: damn!  that must be a way to single-line this :(

Comment: +1, but ... it isn't clear from the question whether it is just the first match in the file that's needed, or every match.  Supporting 'first' is the fact that the examples don't have a line for the `</body>` tag which is presumably present in the files cited.  Your output with multiple lines matched is going to be interesting, with a line number without prefix for the second and subsequent matches in the same file.

Comment: The hard part is finding the line number -- without that, the whole thing could be done with the `-exec` and `-printf` options to `find`.  I don't see a way to get `grep` to output only the line number; `awk '/body/ {print NR; exit}'` does work, though.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler -- the `-m1` option to `grep` is supposed (according to the man page) output only the first match, avoiding the problem you mention.

Comment: @MK: probably not a way to do that in one line unless you're into sado-masochistic Perl (Python, ...), or similarly contorted shell (the whole script could be put on one line if you add semi-colons in the relevant places).  The trailing backslash on the first line is, incidentally, unnecessary; this is a real shell, not a sea shell that is in use.

Comment: Re: `grep -m1` - Ah, another GNU extension and I didn't notice that it was there.  Less safe when the tag is Unix rather than Linux (or MacOS X).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler -- I removed that from the code now since it now uses `awk`.  I don't know portable the `awk` features I'm using are, though.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler -- Oops, I did forget the file name.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: On Solaris 9, the `oawk` (old `awk`) program accepts your `exit`; you are pretty safe with that.

Answer (score 1):

First of, there's no file creation date recorded in UNIX. For line numbers, this would fit:

```
find . -type f -iname '*index*jsp' -exec grep -n body '{}' ';'
```

Comment: Yes there is.  Look at the find -ctime parameter.  It just doesn't show up in ls normally, but it does with the -c parameter.

Comment: ctime is inode change time, not file creation time.

Answer (score 1):

1) you have to mask *index*jsp. Else the shell will resolve it, and if you happen to have a file a-index-0.jsp, find will be confronted with that substitution.

```
 find . -type f -iname "*index*jsp" -print | xargs ls -t | xargs grep body
```

2) print is, what find does by default.

```
 find . -type f -iname "*index*jsp" | xargs ls -t | xargs grep body
```

3) find has the possibility to call external programs with -exec; no need to call xargs by pipe.

```
 find . -type f -iname "*index*jsp" -exec ls -t {} ";" -exec grep -n body {} ";"
```

4) Formatting the output of find can be done by find itself - cTime, mTime and breakfeasttime. ;) See yourself (man find) for the gazillion of options for -printf, especially for times.

```
 find tmp -type f -iname "*index*jsp" -printf "%H/%f\t %CD\t" -exec grep -n body {} ";"
```

5) Why?

If your find, like GNU-find, has these options, you don't have to sanitize against blanks in filenames. Blanks in filenames are hard to handle - `find -print0 | xargs ...` can do it, but you don't have to do it, if you stay in find. But if you call "ls", you're lost.

Maybe your current command yields no file with blanks/newlines/tabs in the name. Fine. But learning the better way, and communicating it constantly prevents errors later and for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name index* | xargs ls -t | xargs grep -Z body \
    | tr -s " " \
    | cut -d $'\0' -f 1 | uniq \
    | xargs -n 1 -I {} -exec sh -c \ "
        echo -n {} \" \"; \
        ls -lt {} | tr -s \" \" | cut -d \" \" -f 6; \
        grep -n body {} | cut -d ":" -f 1
    "
```

That's about as close as I can get on it.